# Spring bean several parameters setter

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, javabeans

How to invoke 2 parameters setter in spring bean? I know that's work with constructor, but imagine that I have method `void setMyFoo(int i, boolean b);`.

How can I call it from xml?

```
<property name="MyFoo">
  //what should be there ????
</property>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to java bean convention,a setter with two parameter is not a setter.Setter and getter are related to only one property at a time.

However if you want,your setter to contains multiple vales ,you can use map or list as a properties which further contains other(primitives).

Comment: Could you give an example which addresses the OP's question?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Properties are expected to have a corresponding setter method with a single parameter.